# Unable to read last record of CSV file in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, csv, logic

I have a CSV File in the following format :

```
"FIELD1";"FIELD2";"FIELD3";"FIELD4";"FIELD5";"FIELD6";  
"BABY";"333333";"0100-0100";"1";"3/2/2018";"88888";  
"BABY";"333333";"0100-0200";"2";"3/3/2018";"88888";  
"BABY";"444444";"0100-0300";"3";"3/4/2018";"88888";
```

I need to update a transaction table and a master table, where transaction and master tables have field2 as common between them, so for multiple rows of transaction table, there should be only 1 row of master, and the transaction table should be updated first followed by the Master table.

The code below reads only 2 records and successfully updates both tables, but when the third (last) row is read, it just skips updating both tables. I need help in getting the code to update all records in the file properly.

```
Private Sub UpdateFromFile()

    Dim strSql As New StringBuilder()
    Dim strSql1 As New StringBuilder()

    'Read the CSV file
    Dim parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(path:="C:\IMPORTDATA\TEST.CSV") With {
        .Delimiters = New String() {";"},
        .HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True,
        .TrimWhiteSpace = True
    }

    Dim RowValues As String()
    Dim PrevRowValues As String()
    Dim PrevRefNumber As String = ""

    '--First line is header, skip it
    parser.ReadLine()
    PrevRefNumber = ""

    Dim IsFirstTime As Boolean = True

    Do Until parser.EndOfData

        Do While True

            RowValues = parser.ReadFields()

            If IsFirstTime Then
                PrevRefNumber = RowValues(1)
                IsFirstTime = False
            End If

            If PrevRefNumber <> RowValues(1) Then
                Exit Do
            End If

            PrevRowValues = RowValues

            LblStatus.Text = "Status: Writing Line " & i.ToString & "..."
            strSql.AppendFormat("INSERT INTO ""Transaction"" (""Field1"", ""Field2"", ""Field3"", ""Field4"", ""Field5"") VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}',{3},'{4}')", RowValues(0), RowValues(1), RowValues(2), CDbl(RowValues(3)), RowValues(5))
            MessageBox.Show(strSql.ToString)

        Loop

        LblStatus.Text = "Status: Writing Master File..."

        strSql1.AppendFormat("INSERT INTO ""Master"" (""Field1"", ""Field2"", ""Field3"") VALUES ( '{0}', '{1}', '{2}')", PrevRowValues(0), PrevRowValues(1), PrevRowValues(5))
        MessageBox.Show(strSql1.ToString)

        PrevRefNumber = RowValues(1)
        strSql1.Clear()
    Loop

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Have you actually debugged your code, i.e. set a breakpoint and stepped through the code line by line? I'll wager not. You need to do that before posting here. I would expect that the issue has something to do with having nested loops but debugging properly should make it obvious.

Comment: @jmcilhinney in fact i did already, and i know what the problem is too, but i am unable to solve the logic, its just not coming into my head :)

Comment: In that case, you must have more relevant information to pass on to us than you included in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the code working, if someone is interested...

```
'--TextField Parser is used to read the csv file 
Dim parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(path:="C:\IMPORTDATA\TEST.CSV") With {
        .Delimiters = New String() {";"}, ' fields are separated by semicolon
        .HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True, ' each of the values is enclosed with double quotes
        .TrimWhiteSpace = True
    }

Dim RowValues As String()
Dim PrevRowValues As String()
Dim PrevRefNumber As String = ""
Dim IsRefNumberSame As Boolean = False
Dim i As Integer = 1

    '--First line is header, skip it
    parser.ReadLine()

    Dim IsFirstTime As Boolean = True
Dim IsTransWritten As Boolean = False

Do While Not parser.EndOfData
            RowValues = parser.ReadFields


If IsFirstTime Then
            PrevRefNumber = RowValues(1)
            IsFirstTime = False
        End If

If PrevRefNumber <> RowValues(1) Then
            strSql1.AppendFormat("INSERT INTO ""master"" (""f1"", ""f2"", ""f3"") VALUES ( '{0}', '{1}', '{2}')", PrevRowValues(0), PrevRowValues(1), PrevRowValues(5))
            MessageBox.Show(strSql1.ToString)
            strSql1.Clear()
            PrevRefNumber = RowValues(1)
End If


        strSql.AppendFormat("INSERT INTO ""trans"" (""f1"", ""f2"", ""f3"", ""f4"", ""f5"", ""f6"") VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}',{3},'{4}',{5} )", RowValues(0), RowValues(1), RowValues(2), CDbl(RowValues(3)), RowValues(5), 1)
        MessageBox.Show(strSql.ToString)
        strSql.Clear()
        PrevRowValues = RowValues

Loop

    strSql1.AppendFormat("INSERT INTO ""master"" (""f1"", ""f2"", ""f3"") VALUES ( '{0}', '{1}', '{2}')", RowValues(0), RowValues(1), RowValues(5))
    MessageBox.Show(strSql1.ToString)
```